# Best way to turn an array into a 2D array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Say I have an array:

```
s = ["Abc", 123, "Abc", 123, "Abc", 123, "Abc", 123, "Abc", 123]
```

What would be the best way to turn it into

```
array = [["Abc",123]["Abc",123]["Abc",123]["Abc",123]["Abc",123]
```

Comment: Your expected output is not valid Ruby expression.

Comment: ...and it's not just the missing commas. As an aside, "s", as in "string", is not the best name for an array. "a", "arr" or "array" would be more fitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

> **each_slice(n) { ... } → nil**
>   **each_slice(n) → an_enumerator**
>   Iterates the given block for each slice of `n` elements. If no block is given, returns an enumerator.

So you'd say:

```
s.each_slice(2).to_a
```

or

```
s.each_slice(2).entries
```